# Error al mostrar resultados en View yii framework 1

Tags: php, yii

estoy comenzando en el mundo yii framework en la version 1.1 y me es imposible visualizar los registros traidos desde una consulta pura. hace dias que no puedo solucionarlo , seguramente sea algo sencillo pero con mi pobre conocimiento no lo e podido solucionar aun. Les muestro mi codigo a ver si me pueden ayudar.

mi modelo es :

```
public function traerRecibos()
{
return Yii::app()->db->createCommand(‘select idrecibo from tbl_recibo’)->queryAll();
}
```

mi Controller es :

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new TblRecibo('traerRecibos');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if (isset($_GET['TblRecibo']))
        $model->attributes = $_GET['TblRecibo'];
    $this->render('index', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

Mi vista es:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'tbl-recibo-grid', 'dataProvider'=>$model->traerRecibos(), 
 'columns'=>array( 
'idRecibo',
), )); ?>
```

al ejecutar este codigo sencillo el error es el siguiente:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\yii1115\framework\zii\widgets\CBaseListView.php on line 111
```

y se observa esta imagen con el error completo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No puedo encontrar la solucion espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Gracias y Saludos!

Comment: revisa esto, https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/call-to-a-member-function-getdata-on-a-non-object/54871 y observa como trae la informacion del modale referenciado

Comment: no me funciono, asique ahora estoy probando de hacerlo en CDbCriteria , no me genera ningun error pero no visualizo los datos de las columnas joins en la gridview